# Python function that converts semicolons and dashes to spaces in a string

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

How would I write a simple python function that takes in a string and fixes it by replacing the semis and dashes to spaces? For example:

- input string: This;is;an-example-string
- output string: This is an example string

I believe I can use regex (from googling) but I am not sure how that works? I would assume regex is easier and more concise than to manually parse this? thanks

Comment: In this case using regex would be overdimensionized. Simply use the string type-related method `replace`. As follows `"This;is;an-example-string".replace('-',' ').replace(';',' ')`.

Comment: Why do you think you need a regular expression? Just replace the characters with the string `replace` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use regex, this is how you'd do it:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('[;-]', ' ', string)
'This is an example string'
```

OTOH, regex seems overkill here. You could chain two `str.replace` calls, or use `str.translate` (python3.x).

```
>>> string.translate(str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(';-', ' ')))
'This is an example string'
```

For python2.x, you'd `import string as st` first, and then call `st.maketrans` in the same way.

The advantage of `translate` over `replace` is that it is really fast, and will need only one call regardless of the number/type of replacements to be done.

Comment: Worth mentioning that `type object 'str' has no attribute 'maketrans'` under Python 27.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub()` in python to look for a pattern in a string and replace it with other pattern. In this case you can look for pattern as `[a-z&A-Z&0-9]` 
and if other than these characters exist in a string replace it with a space.

`re.sub(pattern, repl, string)`

```
import re

value = "This;is;an-example-string output string:"

new_value = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9 \n\.]', ' ', value)

print (new_value)
```

Comment: Nope, this is not all inclusive, and will swap out any other special character besides the semi colon or hyphen. Why would you consider this better than `[^;-]`?